Parent and child vs. flat structure in transactions
I am designing a system that records stock transactions for a product. Some product types use serial numbers for traceability and some products types do not serialize items.
When recording stock transactions, I could see designing the ledger in two ways: 1) recording by parent (the product), and then linking to a child table for serial numbers when those are required, or 2) recording by the most granular entity, either a product by itself or a product and serial combo.
Below is a picture clarifying the structure. I'd like to know if one is normalized and the other is not, or if they both are normal and it's a matter of preference based on the needs of the system and user.
NOTE: I am not looking for this to be an opinion-based question, I am wondering if there is an objectively better method. Do the rules of normalization have guidance on this? If they do not, and either would work, then I would find that in and of itself an interesting insight.

